# Not Updating records from the table in SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a problem updating my records when I edit it. I think it's on the DatabaseHandler because I don't know the right codes on how to update the database. Can someone help me fix this?

```
btn_Update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String ReportCode = tv_Code.getText().toString();

        //Casting and conversion for district code
        String District = spn_District.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Cursor rDistrict = databaseHandler.getReport_DistrictCode(District);
        String DistrictCode = rDistrict.getString(rDistrict.getColumnIndex(Constants.DISTRICT_CODE));

        //Casting and conversion for province id
        String Province = spn_Province.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Cursor rProvince = databaseHandler.getReport_ProvinceId(Province);
        String ProvinceCode = rProvince.getString(rProvince.getColumnIndex(Constants.PROVINCE_ID));

        //Casting and conversion for InfoType id
        String InfoType = spn_InfoType.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Cursor rInfoType = databaseHandler.getReport_InfoTypeCode(InfoType);
        String InfoTypeCode = rInfoType.getString(rInfoType.getColumnIndex(Constants.INFORMATIONTYPE_CODE));

        int IsCompetitor = chkString;
        String DateObserved = txt_Date.getText().toString();
        String Remarks = txt_Remarks.getText().toString();

        //UPDATE IREPORT
        databaseHandler.UpdateReport(new Cons_iReport (ReportCode, InfoTypeCode, DistrictCode, ProvinceCode, DateObserved, IsCompetitor, Remarks));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UPDATE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public void UpdateReport(Cons_iReport save){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_CODE, save.getReportCode()); // Save Report Code
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_DISTRICTCODE, save.getDistrict()); // Save District
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_PROVINCECODE, save.getProvince()); // Save Province
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_ISCOMPETITOR, save.getCompetitor()); // Save isCompetitor
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_INFOTYPECODE, save.getInfoType()); // Save infoType
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_DATEOBSERVED, save.getDateObserved()); // Save Date Observed
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_REMARKS, save.getRemarks()); // Save Remarks

    db.update(Constants.TABLE_REPORT, values, Constants.REPORT_CODE+" = ?", null);
    db.close(); 
}
```

Comment: start by checking the return value of db.update.

Comment: then, read update documentation and see that your selection is flawed. your ? cannot be matched to a null array of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `whereArgs` are `null`

```
db.update(Constants.TABLE_REPORT, values, Constants.REPORT_CODE+" = ?", null);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

You need to supply them or it will not find any records to update.

It's the equivalent of saying "update the records where Constants.REPORT_CODE equals ... nothing". You need to tell it what REPORT_CODE to update.